# File Upload control inside a multiview control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a mutliview inside a ContentTemplate and UpdatePanel in my page. Inside the multiview, I have 2 views. In one of the views, I have a file upload control like so.

```
<tr id="Tr10" height="22px" runat="server" >
<td colspan="3"><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Upload approval document:"></asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="uplDocument" runat="server" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=true;"/>    
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveDoc" runat="server" Text="Save" onkeyup="javascript:shouldsubmit=true;"/>                                                  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td><asp:Label ID="lblDoc" runat="server" Text="Document:"></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/SetupStudentFeeRequestApproval.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
</td></tr>
```

My requirement is that the path of the uploaded file should be displayed in **lnkDoc**. But the file is not getting uploaded. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but had a problem with this myself today and thought I'd share the answer.

Basically, `input type="file"` controls (aka html rendered by `asp:FileUpload` control) cannot persist state across postbacks.

This is a security consideration designed to prevent attempts at retrieving other files from a  user's computer - essentially the only way to persist state would be to store the file path and restore it to the file upload when the page reloaded - this allows the possibility to enter a different path (to any file on the user's computer potentially) and so the browser blocks this behaviour.

I'm not sure what you want to do with the file as you mention displaying the file path in the next view but, if you're doing that because you're planning on uploading the file later in the process, then the only thing you can do is to upload the file to a temp folder when the user clicks btnSaveDoc and then use it later when you need it.

Hope this helps.